# create partitioned table from JSON file in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, partitioning

I would like to create a partitioned table in BigQuery. The schema for the table is in JSON format stored in my local path.

I would like to create this table with partition from the JSON file using "bq mk -t" command. Kindly help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
bk mk  --table --schema=file.json  PROJECTID:DATASET.TABLE
```

Hope the above example helps.

you can [refer to the more options](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/using-dml-with-partitioned-tables#updating_data).

Answer (score 0):

One recommendation to use the JSON format for creating the bigquery tables.
(1) If we decide to use the partition the table for better performance use the pseudo partition (**_PARTITIONTIME** or **_PARTITITIONDATE**).
(2) Example, partition_date is the column which has the data type of TIMESTAMP (we can use data type column DATE also).

```
     {
    
      "name": "partition_date",
      "type": "TIMESTAMP",
      "mode": "NULLABLE",
      "timePartitioning": {
      "type": "DAY"
      },
      "field" : [
           {
            "name": "partition_date",
            "type": "TIMESTAMP"
           } 
            
        ]

    },
```